# Rows for which the WHERE condition evaluates to NULL?

Tags: mysql, null

After executing the following query in MySQLWorkbench, only the first row was returned.

```
select * from (
  select true as a
  union select false as a
  union select null as a
) x
where a
```

My takeaway from this is that rows such that the query's `where` clause evaluates to `null` will be filtered out. However, I could not find documentation of this behavior, so I wanted to check whether I can assume this behavior will always occur before writing queries that rely on it. Hence,

1. Will this behavior always occur, and if so,
2. Is there documentation of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is as expected.

From the docs(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html):

> In MySQL, 0 or NULL means false and anything else means true. The default truth value from a boolean operation is 1.

So both null and false are filtered out and only row with true is returned.